# Angular guard componentless route with optional id

Tags: angular

I'm working on restricting routes with API call checking if there is permissions for that. Current routes are

```
{
    path: '',
    children: [
        { path: '', component: HomeComponent},
        { path: ':id', component: HomeComponent },
        { path: 'unauthorized', component: UnauthorizedComponent },
        { path: '**', redirectTo: '' }
    ]
}
```

What I want is to restrict boh `''` and `:id` with the guard and in it I have re route to `unauthorized` but if I apply `canActivate` to the root path it causes circular calls because it redirects to `unauthorized` which is guarded as well and it blocks the UI. If I apply it to the childs which I want to protect It doesn't get called.

Answer (score 1):

```
{
    path: '',
    children: [
        { path: '', canActivate: [WhateverService], children: [
          { path: '', component: HomeComponent},
          { path: ':id', component: HomeComponent },
        ]},
        { path: 'unauthorized', component: UnauthorizedComponent },
        { path: '**', redirectTo: '' }
    ]
}
```

This should do the trick. It's just basic route grouping.